# Internet breaks on Debian KDE when connected to wired ethernet that does not have internet. Also WiFi connects and has internet

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, internet, ethernet

Running Debian KDE Plasma on a desktop computer that is connected:

- Via a wired ethernet connection to another device and no internet.
- Via a wireless connection that has internet

I am not able to access the internet.

I installed Debian using a Live USB, and during the installation the computer had internet connection over the wireless and could use it.

How can I continue with connection internet? How can I obtain regular interval check ports which have internet and automatically connect.

Comment: I do not know why that would be.  Is your Ethernet and Wireless (both) on a Router.  That way connections should not break.

Comment: I live all debian installation. I achieve only connman applet. And I solve near like below.                                  
 nano /etc/connman/main.conf
[General]
DefaultAutoConnectTechnologies = wifi,ethernet
PreferredTechnologies=wifi,ethernet

Answer (score 0):

This is not autodetect but if your wired ethernet connection no internet. Edit the connection and select under IPv4 Settings -> Routes -> "Use this connection only for resources on its network"